# I'm setting up a private cloud using openstack in vmware. Problem is I set statc ip and now can not connect to internet

Tags: networking, maas

I have installed maas and everything. and after setting static ip and reboot I cant connect to internet, I can ping to the internal network though. 
I used "sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces" to edit the ip.
I'm new to all of this but I have tried a few things from askubuntu community but didnt find any solution.

Comment: This is about your network configuration/layout, not Ubuntu.

Comment: I know its about network config. but how do i set it so that I can access internet ??

Comment: If u revert the changes and use dhclient it works again?

Comment: yes it works fine when I revert it to dhcp again.